# MySQLi_query syntax error

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I have been trying to figure this out for hours... Here is the code:

```
function add_user($data) {
$user_table = USER_TABLE;
$first_name = ($data['first_name']);
$last_name =($data['last_name']);
$email_address = ($data['email_address']);
$drivers_license_id = ($data['drivers_license_id']);
$gender = ($data['gender']);
$password =($data['password']);
$query = "INSERT INTO $user_table (
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email_address,
        drivers_license_id,
        gender,
        password
    ) VALUES (
        '$first_name',
        '$last_name',
        '$email_address',
        '$drivers_license_id',
        '$gender',
        '$password')";
if (mysqli_query($connection,'$query',MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) return true;
error_log("Failed to create user: " . mysqli_error($error_get_last));
return false;
```

I am receiving syntax error. I am not sure if I should return the query to false, or leave it as true. 
   Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc. on line 122
   Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\etc. on line 122
   Warning: mysqli_query() expects at most 3 parameters, 4 given in       C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: 1) Your connection handler `$connection` is not available in the scope of your function. Either use `global` or pass the connection handler `$connection` to your `add_user()` function as an argument(passing the parameter is better than using `global`). 2) Remove those single quotes around `$query`.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul Like this: " function add_user($data, $connection){ etc."

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also, make sure that you're passing the connection handler when *actually* calling the `add_user()` function, like this: `add_user($your_data, $connection);`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the string "$query" rather than passing the query itself. Your mysqli_query() should look like:

```
mysqli_query($connection,$query,MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)
```

Comment: I got this notice when I tried that :"Notice: Undefined variable: connection in etc."  and "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in"

Comment: Your error indicates that your $connection does not exist. @RajdeepPaul gave you good advice, to pass connection var to the function or include it using global

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query($connection,'$query',MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)` should be `mysqli_query($connection,$query,MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)`

I should mention this is potentially a very unsafe query. You do not appear to be sanitizing the variables you use, which would allow someone to attack you with sql injection.

Read this:
https://www.troyhunt.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
function add_user($data) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database_name');
    $query = "INSERT INTO `USER_TABLE` (
        `first_name`,
        `last_name`,
        `email_address`,
        `drivers_license_id`,
        `gender`,
        `password`
    ) VALUES (
       $data['first_name'],
        $data['last_name'],
        $data['email_address'],
        $data['drivers_license_id'],
        $data['gender'],
        $data['password'])";
    if (mysqli_query($connection,'$query',MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
         return true;
    error_log("Failed to create user: " . mysqli_error($error_get_last));
    return false;
```

Comment: **add** your **db name** at 'database_name'

Comment: IMHO, creating a separate connection inside `add_user()` function is an overkill. See my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870555/mysqli-query-syntax-error#comment63197908_37870555).